# Access properties from different qml tabs within same tabbedpane

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I have my main.qml that contains a tabbedpane, in which, it has two tabs: tab1 and tab2. 
I would like to be able to change the text from one tab to another.

If I do the same with navigationpane it works but not with tabs apparently. Is there any way I could share information between them? I've tried with signals in c++ but it doesn't work either(I guess it doesnt know the instance ?).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

main.qml:

```
TabbedPane {
Tab {
    Tab1 {
    }
}
Tab {
    Tab2 {
    }
}
attachedObjects: [
    Tab1 {
        id: tab1
    },
    Tab2 {
        id: tab2
    }        
]
}
```

Tab1.qml:

```
Page {
property alias labeltab1: labeltab1
Container {
    Label {
        id: labeltab1
        text: "label tab1"
    }
    Button {
        id: buttontab1
        text: "tab1"
        onClicked: {
            tab2.labeltab2.text = "This is coming from tab1"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Tab2.qml:

```
Page {
property alias labeltab2: labeltab2
Container {
    Label {
        id: labeltab2
        text: "Label tab2"
    }
    Button {
        id: buttontab2
        text: "tab2"
        onClicked: {
            tab1.labeltab1.text = "This is coming from tab2"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's actually simpler with tabs and I found my own solution.

I noticed that momentics cannot detect that "thepane" is linkable and will not suggest its name when typing it from one of the tab. Also, a property with colon will automatically bind the value afterit, as: text: thepane.mystring

When clicking on buttons, it changes the value of mystring thus changing both labels texts.

main.qml

```
TabbedPane {
id: thepane
property string mystring
Tab {
    Tab1 {

    }
}
Tab {
    Tab2 {

    }
}
}
```

Tab1.qml

```
Page {
Container {
    Label {
        id: labeltab1
        text: thepane.mystring
    }
    Button {
        id: buttontab1
        text: "tab1"
        onClicked: {
            thepane.mystring = "This is coming form tab1"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Tab2.qml

```
Page {
Container {
    Label {
        id: labeltab2
        text: thepane.mystring
    }
    Button {
        id: buttontab2
        text: "tab2"
        onClicked: {
            thepane.mystring = "This is coming from tab2"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your idea.
I changed the code. Now it is better for me, maybe for other one people :)

main.qml

```
TabbedPane {
    id: main_Pane

    property string action_1
    property string action_2

    Tab {
        Tab1 {}
    }

    Tab {
        Tab2 {}
    }
}
```

Tab1.qml

```
Page {

    Container {

        Label {
            text: main_Pane.action_1
        }
        Button {
            text: "Button 1"

            onClicked: {
                main_Pane.action_2 = "This is action form Tab1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tab2.qml

```
Page {

    Container {

        Label {
            text: main_Pane.action_2
        }
        Button {
            text: "Button 2"

            onClicked: {
                main_Pane.action_1 = "This is action from Tab2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```